# How to restore a custom toolbar in XP

Tags: windows-xp, backup, toolbar

A few months ago I asked where the details of a custom toolbar were located with a view to restoring a backup. With the assistance of Psycogeek I got to the bottom of it.  I offer you the batch scripts which solved the problem.

Comment: Next time please don't post a question again. Try to get the old question reopened by coming to [Meta], flagging for attention, or asking for help in [chat].